# WebRTC: what's the benefit over sockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, p2p

Imagin text chat app. Users can connect to chat by link.

To send messages to all users every user must have Peer2Peer WebRTC connection with all users. It is many-to-many.
When new user connect to chat, all current users must receive the new user's SDP. The only way current users can get new user's SDP is by using Signling Server.

Thus: every user must have alive socket connection with Signling Server. Socket connection must be alive all time user in chat.
If all users have full time alive socket connection - what's the benefit of WebRTC ?

Answer (score 0):

1. The signaling server allows new users to efficiently exchange SDP information with all existing peers without needing direct connections. It acts as a central hub for signaling data transfer.
2. Even with a signaling server, the actual media transfer occurs directly between peers via WebRTC without going through the server. So it still allows decentralization and prevents the server from becoming a bandwidth bottleneck.
3. The server can implement optimization techniques like clustering users or limiting connections based on proximity. This helps reduce the degree of interconnectivity needed between all peers.
4. The server can facilitate peer discovery and reconnections, so peers are not dependent on knowing the identity of every other peer explicitly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).